# Select from a field containing spaces using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to query on a field/column/table in a MySQL DB where the field type is varchar, but some values contains spaces. In my query, I tried to put the exact string to match on in single quotes in a where clause. However, the only rows that are returned are the strings that do not contain spaces.

Here are the values stored in the table/column:

[image]

Here is the query and the result that is only returning fields without spaces:

[image]

I expected to find a row for "New Business", a row for "Monetary Endorsement", etc. Any idea on how I can modify my query to return the desired fields? Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the other values have leading or trailing spaces. You can either use one of the suggestion below:

1.) Use `TRIM()`

```
WHERE TRIM(PTD_TRANS_TYPE) = 'NEW BUSINESS'
```

2.) Use `LIKE`

```
WHERE PTD_TRANS_TYPE LIKE '%NEW BUSINESS%'
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/270320/1).